# Create PDF using byte array from database

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, arrays

I am trying to create pdf file from byte array which is coming from database.The code runs fine and create the pdf file but I cant open the file it shows that file is corrupted or damaged. Here I show my full code, please point out what I want to change or which way is correct to achieve this type of code. Thanks.

**TestPDF:**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class TestPDF {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String jdbcClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    String host="hostname",port="50000",db="dbname",dbuser="user",dbpass="pass";
    String url="jdbc:db2://"+host+":"+port+"/"+db;
    String user=dbuser;
    String password=dbpass;

    Connection con = null;
    InputStream fetchStream = null;
    try{
        //Load class into memory
        Class.forName(jdbcClassName);
        //Establish connection
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from tgpoa01.aud_trail_dtl WHERE AUD_TRAIL_REC_ID = '-9223372036798517556'");
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next())
    {

    fetchStream = rs.getBinaryStream("AUD_TRAIL_MSG_TX");

    if(rs.getString("AUD_PRCS_STAGE_CD").equals("CONT")){

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fetchStream.read(buf)) != -1;) {
    bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
    System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
    }
    System.out.println("Byte array is="+bos);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    File someFile = new File("d://Output_File.pdf");
    try{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }

    }


    }
    }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Exception in getting PDF : "+e);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: never catch exception without handle it. add `e.printStacktrace()` to inside the catch block to see if an exception occurs

Comment: even if I add printStackTrace() no error came

Comment: You have 3 `catch`in there. One of them swallows the `Exception`

Comment: no it actually runs fine and create the pdf file but that created pdf file is not opening

Comment: You have `System.out.println` outputs. Do they show sensible data? And please share the broken PDF for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop you're using to read the `bytes` from the DB looks kind of odd to me. Can you try one of these (*completely untested*) alternatives please:

**Using `ResultSet.getBinaryStream(...)`:**

```
if ( rs.next() ) {

    if ( rs.getString("AUD_PRCS_STAGE_CD").equals("CONT") ) {

        File someFile = new File("d://Output_File.pdf");        
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
        fetchStream = rs.getBinaryStream("AUD_TRAIL_MSG_TX");
        while (fetchStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
            fos.write(buffer);
        }
        fos.close();        

    }

}
```

**Using `ResultSet.getBlob(...)`:**

```
if ( rs.next() ) {

    if ( rs.getString("AUD_PRCS_STAGE_CD").equals("CONT") ) {

        Blob blob = rs.getBlob("AUD_TRAIL_MSG_TX");
        byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());

        File someFile = new File("d://Output_File.pdf");        
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(someFile);
        fos.write(bytes);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: actually AUD_TRAIL_MSG_TX datatype in database is bytes[] thats why am struggling

Comment: That's interesting. Are you able to get the database column definitions? Something along the lines of `DESC tgpoa01.aud_trail_dtl;`. It would help to put the result into your original question if you can. Also, what type of dtabase is it (MySQL, Oracle, ...)?

Comment: its a DB2 database, I need to print the byte array value. But am not sure before printing the byte array, it needs to convert to some other datatype or not.

Comment: I guess it depends on how it was stored... have you access to that code?

Comment: it is stored in byte datatype only

Comment: I can't help any more than that. This code should help in this scenario (even your own code should). Last effort: update jdbc drivers?